# Convert nested dictionary data in a column into new rows and new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am still pretty new with python and pandas. I am working with some data that consists of citations for articles, where the citations consist of multiple sources in one cell. The citations are Title and year for multiple sources for each article title as shown image 1. [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBtLi.jpg)

```
           article title                                                                                     source citations article author
0  Essential mathematics    title: Elementary Statistics, year: 2011, title: Linear Algebra and it's applications, year: 2016     J. Hemming
1    Trading for dummies  title: Currency Trading for dummies, year: 2015, title: The complete Penny stock course, year: 2018      A. Clarke
```

I want to break out these citations to look like image 2 (blue arrow pointing to what I am trying to accomplish), where the citations title and year have their own columns. I have played around with the explode function, but I can get it to work correctly for what I am trying to do.  [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7jwk.jpg)

Also, I was wondering what one can do if the pattern under the source citations was not always consistent for each cell as shown in image 3 here [image] , where the 'About the Earth' row has a different pattern from the other 2 rows.

Reply to option 2: image 3 [image: image 3]

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Extract the matching occurences of a regex pattern then join the resulting matches with original dataframe

```
m = df['source citations'].str.extractall(r'title:\s*([^,]+),\s*year:\s*(\d+)')
m.columns = ['source_title', 'source_year']

df1 = df.join(m.droplevel(1))
```

Option 2: If the order of the pattern is not fixed, we can use `findall` to extract all the matching key value pairs. Then we can convert the pairs to a dictionary and create a new dataframe. Finally, we can join this new dataframe back with the original dataframe.

```
m = df['source citations'].str.findall(r'\s*([^:,]+):\s*([^,]+)')
df1 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(map(dict, m), index=m.index))
```

---

```
print(df1)

           article title                                                                                     source citations article author                          source_title source_year
0  Essential mathematics    title: Elementary Statistics, year: 2011, title: Linear Algebra and it's applications, year: 2016     J. Hemming                 Elementary Statistics        2011
0  Essential mathematics    title: Elementary Statistics, year: 2011, title: Linear Algebra and it's applications, year: 2016     J. Hemming  Linear Algebra and it's applications        2016
1    Trading for dummies  title: Currency Trading for dummies, year: 2015, title: The complete Penny stock course, year: 2018      A. Clarke          Currency Trading for dummies        2015
1    Trading for dummies  title: Currency Trading for dummies, year: 2015, title: The complete Penny stock course, year: 2018      A. Clarke       The complete Penny stock course        2018
```

Comment: Shubham, Thank-you! Your method worked very well. I added more information for the source citations (country and category) -shown in image 3-and your method worked. However, there is one issue. The method appears to depend on the pattern of the source citations data to always be consistent (title, year, country, category). Is there anything one could do if some of the cells under source citations strayed away from the pattern such as shown in image 3, for article ‘About the Earth’ highlighted in yellow where the pattern is instead (title, country, category, year) to produce the same effect?

Comment: @jayh Unless you want to make something Really complex, you're going to need to make sure the data is valid JSON (with `"` around keys and values, for example)

Comment: @jayh Please check the edit specifically Option 2.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I tried option 2. For the portion that converts the pairs to a dictionary and creates a new dataframe, It doesn’t look like it mapped all of the key value pairs to produce the final dataframe (df1.) The final merged data frame df1 doesn’t have all of the data from the source citations (image 3). It looks like only the last key-value pairs in the source citations were used for df1. I really appreciate all of the help, I am still learning!

Comment: @MatBailie This is fake data, but its structure looks like some data I am looking at from work. There was no JSON formatting, particularly with the citations.